# How to add secondary region Redis cluster and global datastore using CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I am trying to create Redis Cluster across the region. Using this below CloudFormation template I am not able to see the secondary cluster and global store. The template is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'redis cluster for sample application'
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
    - Label:
        default: 'ElastiCache Parameters'
      Parameters:
      - EngineVersion
      - CacheNodeType
      - TransitEncryption
      #- AuthToken
      - NumShards
      - NumReplicas
    - Label:
        default: 'Alerting Parameters'
      Parameters:
      - CPUUtilizationThreshold
      - DatabaseMemoryUsagePercentageThreshold
      - SwapUsageThreshold
      - EvictionsThreshold
      - ReplicationLagThreshold
Parameters:

  EngineVersion:
    Description: 'Redis version'
    Type: String
    Default: '7.0'
    AllowedValues: ['7.0', '6.2', '6.0', '5.0.6', '5.0.5', '5.0.4', '5.0.3', '5.0.0', '4.0.10', '3.2.6'] # aws elasticache describe-cache-engine-versions --engine redis --query "CacheEngineVersions[].EngineVersion"
  CacheNodeType:
    Description: 'The compute and memory capacity of the nodes in the node group (shard).'
    Type: 'String'
    Default: 'cache.m5.xlarge'
  TransitEncryption:
    Description: 'Enable encryption for data in transit? (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html)'
    Type: 'String'
    Default: 'true'
    AllowedValues:
    - 'true'
    - 'false'
  AccountEnv:
    Description: 'Type of Environment.'
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/delta/account/environment'
  NumShards:
    Description: 'Number of shards in the cluster.'
    Type: 'Number'
    Default: 2
    MinValue: 1
    MaxValue: 250
  NumReplicas:
    Description: 'Number of replicas per shard.'
    Type: 'Number'
    Default: 2
    MinValue: 0
    MaxValue: 5
  CPUUtilizationThreshold:
    Description: 'The maximum percentage of CPU usage (set to -1 to disable).'
    Type: Number
    Default: 80
    MinValue: -1
    MaxValue: 100
  DatabaseMemoryUsagePercentageThreshold:
    Description: 'The maximum percentage of memory usage (set to -1 to disable).'
    Type: Number
    Default: 90
    MinValue: -1
    MaxValue: 100
  SwapUsageThreshold:
    Description: 'The maximum bytes of swap usage (set to -1 to disable).'
    Type: Number
    Default: 67108864 # 64 MB in Bytes
    MinValue: -1
  EvictionsThreshold:
    Description: 'The maximum number of evictions (set to -1 to disable).'
    Type: Number
    Default: 1000
    MinValue: -1
  ReplicationLagThreshold:
    Description: 'The maximum seconds of replication lag (set to -1 to disable).'
    Type: Number
    Default: 30
    MinValue: -1
  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: Environment Param Name
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/delta/vpc/privatesubnet1aid'
  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: Environment Param Name
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/delta/vpc/privatesubnet2aid'
  PrivateSubnet3:
    Description: Environment Param Name
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/delta/vpc/privatesubnet3aid' 
  VPC:
    Description: vpc id parameter
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/delta/vpc/vpcid'    
  LambdaSecurityGroup:
    Description: Lambda function security group
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: '/delta/sample/lambdafunc/securitygrp' 
  ProjectName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'sample-test'    
Mappings:
  EngineVersionMap:
    '7.0':
      CacheParameterGroupFamily: redis7
    '6.2':
      CacheParameterGroupFamily: 'redis6.x'
    '6.0':
      CacheParameterGroupFamily: 'redis6.x'
    '5.0.6':
      CacheParameterGroupFamily: 'redis5.0'

Conditions:
  HasAutomaticFailoverEnabled: !Not [!Equals [!Ref NumReplicas, 0]]
  HasClusterModeEnabled: !Not [!Equals [!Ref NumShards, 1]]
  HasClusterModeDisabled: !Not [!Condition HasClusterModeEnabled]
Resources:
  AlertTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: !Sub ${ProjectName}-${AccountEnv}
      KmsMasterKeyId: 'alias/sample-cmk'
  CacheParameterGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup'
    Properties:
      CacheParameterGroupFamily: !FindInMap [EngineVersionMap, !Ref EngineVersion, CacheParameterGroupFamily]
      Description: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
      Properties: !If [HasClusterModeEnabled, {'cluster-enabled': 'yes'}, {}]
  CacheSubnetGroupName:
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Redis subnet group
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet3
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupDescription: Enable Redis access 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 6379
          ToPort: 6379
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Project
          Value: !Ref ProjectName
  GlobalReplicationGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElastiCache::GlobalReplicationGroup'
    Properties:
      AutomaticFailoverEnabled: true
      #MultiAZEnabled: !If [HasAutomaticFailoverEnabled, true, false]
      CacheNodeType: !Ref CacheNodeType
      #CacheParameterGroupName: !Ref CacheParameterGroup
      EngineVersion: !Ref EngineVersion
      GlobalNodeGroupCount: 1
      GlobalReplicationGroupDescription: sample-Redis Globalstore'
      GlobalReplicationGroupIdSuffix: sample
      Members:
        - ReplicationGroupId: !Ref ReplicationGroup      
          ReplicationGroupRegion: 'us-west-2'
          Role: PRIMARY         
      RegionalConfigurations: 
        - ReplicationGroupId: !Ref ReplicationGroup
          ReplicationGroupRegion: 'us-east-1'          
  ReplicationGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup'
    Properties:
      ReplicationGroupId: !Sub sample-test-${AccountEnv}
# for prefix please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Redis-Global-Datastores-CLI.html      
      #GlobalReplicationGroupId: sgaui-sample
      ReplicationGroupDescription: sample replication group for Redis
      AtRestEncryptionEnabled: true
      AuthToken: "{{resolve:secretsmanager:sample/redis-cluster/authtoken:SecretString:AuthToken}}"
      #AutomaticFailoverEnabled: !If [HasAutomaticFailoverEnabled, true, false]
      #MultiAZEnabled: !If [HasAutomaticFailoverEnabled, true, false]
      CacheNodeType: !Ref CacheNodeType
      CacheParameterGroupName: !Ref CacheParameterGroup
      CacheSubnetGroupName: !Ref CacheSubnetGroupName
      Engine: redis
      EngineVersion: !Ref EngineVersion
      NotificationTopicArn: !Ref AlertTopic
      NumNodeGroups: !Ref NumShards
      ReplicasPerNodeGroup: !Ref NumReplicas
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref SecurityGroup
      TransitEncryptionEnabled: !Ref TransitEncryption
      Tags:
        - Key: Project
          Value: !Ref ProjectName      
    UpdatePolicy:
      UseOnlineResharding: true
```